# Given a rope of length  , what is the largest square (by area) that can be built given that a side of the square,  , can only be integer values?

Tags: python

Question 1
We have a rope and want to cut the rope into four pieces to make a square. Given a rope of length   , what is the largest square (by area) that can be built given that a side of the square,   , can only be integer values? Units of measurement can be ignored. We are only interested in the numerical value of the solution.

Largest Square
Figure 1: Area of the largest square enclosed by a rope.

Function specifications

Argument(s):

x (float)  →  the length of the rope.
Return:

area (int)  →  the area of the square formed by the rope.
HINT

The perimeter of the square cannot exceed the length of the rope.

I haven't tried anything, it gets me confused

Expected output

```
largest_square(12) == 9
largest_square(41.5) == 100
largest_square(324) == 6561
```

Please help me

Comment: What did you attempt? Post your code - this is not a homework solutions board.

Comment: Not a python question. Just math homework

Answer (score 0):

Does the following program make sense to you?

```
>>> def largest_square(rope):
    side = rope / 4
    area = side * side
    return area

>>> largest_square(5)
1.5625
>>> largest_square(8)
4.0
```